# How can i get my numbers and fortunes to show on this script on button click

Tags: javascript, html

looking to have the user click the button and have the fortune be selecting randomly and shown on the screen with random numbers from 1-100 underneath them. but i can't seem to get everything to display. :(

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
      
   

var quotes = new Array(16) // Add your quotes below
  quotes[0]="Your talents will be recognized and suitably rewarded.";
  quotes[1]="He who hurries cannot walk with dignity.";
  quotes[2]="Your success in life must be earned with earnest efforts.";
  quotes[3]="You love peace.";
  quotes[4]="A friend asks only for your time and not your money.";
  quotes[5]="You will soon inherit a piece of land.";
  quotes[6]="Your luck is about to change.";
  quotes[7]="Things will soon go your way.";
  quotes[8]="He who stands on toilet is high on pot.";
  quotes[8]="Everybody is ignorant, only on different subjects.";
  quotes[9]="Fortune favors the brave.";
  quotes[10]="There is nothing permanent except change.";
  quotes[11]="You haven't failed until you give up.";
  quotes[12]="Your ability to juggle many tasks will take you far.";
  quotes[13]="Broke is only temporary; poor is a state of mind.";
  quotes[14]="Begin nothing until you have considered how it is finished.";
  quotes[15]="A huge fortune at home is not as good as money in use.";

function showFortune() {

   var space = ('      ') // Spacer for between numbers
  var rand_inta = Math.floor(Math.random()*100); // Get first number
  var rand_intb = Math.floor(Math.random()*100); // Get second number
  var rand_intc = Math.floor(Math.random()*100); // Get third number
  var rand_intd = Math.floor(Math.random()*100); // Get fourth number
  var rand_inte = Math.floor(Math.random()*100); // Get fifth number
  var rand_int = Math.floor(Math.random()*16); // Get a number for picking the quote
  document.getElementById(fortuneArea).innerHTML=(quotes[rand_int]); // Put the quote in the box
  

}

  
   
      </script>
```

```html
<form action="">
   <input type="button" value="Show my fortune!" onclick= "showFortune();" />
  </form>
  <div id="fortuneArea"></div>
```

Comment: Try calling `showFortune()` with "fortuneArea" as the parameter. Also, unless your onclick handler returns false, the form will be submitted. So try `onclick="showFortune('fortuneArea'); return false;"`

Comment: where would i put ther fortuneArea?

Comment: like that? still dont work :(

Comment: That's because you deleted `objID` from your code for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('fortuneArea').innerHTML=(quotes[rand_int]);
```

Just add single quotes to id name....

Comment: omg i feel like such a dummie haha i;m so tired lol. thanks a million man.. I missed that big time. you rock!